# grab files from most recently-received email in specific Outlook folder

Tags: powershell, outlook, etl

I want to search a specific Outlook folder, find the most recently-sent email, and save its attachments to a specific dir.

I wrote the following script, but it does not work. Can someone please suggest what needs to be changed in order for it to work?

Also - where can I find a list of Outlook- and Office-specific methods and properties I can use in PowerShell? I tried googling but could not find an official MSDN page for it.

```
#file path
$filepath = “C:\folder”
$account = "JonDoe@company.com"

#set outlook to open
$o = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
$n = $o.GetNamespace(“MAPI”)


$Account = $n.Folders | ? { $_.Name -eq $account };
    $f = $Account.Folders | ? { $_.Name -match 'FolderNameToSearch' };


$date = $f.Items| Select-Object -Property ReceivedTime | Sort-Object ReceivedTime -Descending | Select-Object -Index 0

#Write-Host $date


$f.Items | foreach 
{
   if ($_.ReceivedTime -match $date )
   {
        $_.attachments | foreach 
        {
            #Write-Host $_.filename
            $a = $_.filename
            $_.saveasfile((Join-Path $filepath $a))
        }
   }
}
```

**Edit 3/4/14** - I stepped through the script, and I believe it is failing on `$_.ReceivedTime -match $date`

I added the following code to test the values of the Email `ReceivedTime` datestamps vs the datestamp stored by `$date`:

```
Write-Host "The date I am looking for is $date"

$f.Items | foreach {
   Write-Host $_.ReceivedTime
}
```

and here is part of the output:

```
The date I am looking for is @{ReceivedTime=03/04/2014 03:16:08}
3/4/2014 3:16:08 AM
```

Even though the dates are the same, the data types are different. What is the most elegant way to get `$date` to datetime or vice versa?

Comment: At what point in the script does it deviate from what you expect it to do? You might like to run it in the PowerShell ISE. Set some breakpoints and examine the contents of your variables to see if they are what you expect. You can't expect us to debug your script for you. We have our own boring debugging work to do.

Comment: Beware of the smart quotes ....

Comment: @Trevor, smart quotes don't seem to be a problem for PowerShell. They seem to act just like regular double quotes.

Comment: Guys, please see my edit. I really appreciate your time spent helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're trying too hard. You're looping through your emails twice looking for the exact same email, and that's just redundant. Second, `Get-Date <DateTime Object/DateTime String>` is your friend, but you don't even need it. If you really, really, really want to sort the emails and select the date/time of the first one, then filter them for that one date/time I suppose you can, and here's what you'd want:

```
if ((get-date $_.ReceivedTime) -eq (get-date $date))
```

I think a better solution would be replacing:

```
$date = $f.Items| Select-Object -Property ReceivedTime | Sort-Object ReceivedTime -Descending | Select-Object -Index 0
```

with:

```
$email = $f.Items| Sort-Object ReceivedTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
```

Then you can do things like:

```
Write-Output "Last email received at $($email.receivedtime), attached file(s) are: (if any)
$email.attachments|%{Write-Output $_.filename}
```

and

```
$email.attachments|%{$_.saveasfile((join-path $folder $_.filename))
```

Personally I'd add a `If($email.attachments.count -gt 0){Do Stuff}else{Write-Output "Latest email at $($email.receivedtime) has no attachments!"}` bit in there.

Comment: Sir, take my upvote. Can you please recommend a good reference for learning PowerShell? Is there a book you recommend? You've answered several of my posts here on SO and I'd like to tell you I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Honestly I haven't read a book. I've read several Hey Scripting Guy posts, I used to kind of keep up on MoW's blog, and I'm pretty handy with Google; but it's just self taught with me I'm afraid. Sorry I couldn't be more help on that one. What I can suggest is doing things like `$o|gm` and then looking at the object type and using Google to search for things like "msdn Microsoft.Office.Interop" or "msdn Outlook.ApplicationClass" to find things. I'm happy to help by the way, you at least seem to try and figure things out on your own first and don't just expect to be spoon fed answers.

Comment: I will look into those blogs and exploration techniques. Thanks again!